# Sierpinski’s Gasket Triangle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, fractals

I wrote the Sierpinski’s Gasket Triangle in JavaScript, but I feel the code can be better, especially from [L32 to L47](https://github.com/zeyadetman/chaos/blob/949f1f8b414f0da382e4501807a2f675dd29684a/index.js#L32). Could you make it more organized?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('chaos');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const GenerateRand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
const updateDot = (x, y, point) => {
  let X = Math.min(x,point.x)+(Math.max(x,point.x)-Math.min(x,point.x))/2;
  let Y = Math.min(y,point.y)+(Math.max(y,point.y)-Math.min(y,point.y))/2;
  return {x: X, y: Y};
}
const createDot = (obj) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(obj.x, obj.y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#fc3';
  ctx.stroke();
}

const pA = {x: canvas.width/2, y: 5};
const pB = {x: 5, y: canvas.height-5} 
const pC = {x: canvas.width-5, y: canvas.height-5}

createDot(pA);
createDot(pB);
createDot(pC);

const begin = (iterations) => {
  let x = canvas.width/4;
  let y = canvas.height/2;
    for(let i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
    createDot({x, y});
    let randN = GenerateRand();
    if(randN == 1 || randN == 2) {
      const currentDot = updateDot(x, y, pA);
      x = currentDot.x;
      y = currentDot.y;
    }
    else if(randN == 3 || randN == 4) {
      const currentDot = updateDot(x, y, pB);
      x = currentDot.x;
      y = currentDot.y;
    }
    else if(randN == 5 || randN == 6){
      const currentDot = updateDot(x, y, pC);
      x = currentDot.x;
      y = currentDot.y;
    }
  }
}

let time=0;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
   if(time >= 500) return clearInterval(timer)
   begin(500);
   time++;
}, 200);
```

```html
<div>
      <canvas id="chaos" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Performance

- For positive numbers < 2 ^ 31 use `num | 0` (bitwise or zero) to floor
- You are drawing an arc that is 1 pixel in radius, with the stroke width of 1 the diameter is 3 pixels. This covers an area much greater than the point you sample. Use `fillRect` to draw a single pixel as its much quicker. Better yet as they are all the same color create a single path and use `ctx.rect` to add to it. Render all rect in one pass at the end of `begin` function.
- Avoid creating objects needlessly. Create a working object and use that to hold intermediate values. This can greatly reduce memory allocation and GC overheads. Eg the object you return in `updateDot` is a waste of memory and time.
- If you test two numbers to find the max or min, knowing either means you also know the other and thus do not need to test for it. The long lines `Math.min(p.y, p1.y) + (Math.max(p.y, p1.y) - Math.min(p.y, p1.y)) / 2` can be reduced by a single test and give significant performance improvement.

### Style

- Use `const` for constants. Eg `canvas` and `ctx` should be `const`.
- Capitals only for names of objects that are instantiated with the `new` token. Eg `GenerateRand` should be `generateRand`
- Avoid repeated code by using functions. Eg you create many instances of an object {x,y}, would be better as a function.
- Spaces between operators, commas, etc.
- Use `===` rather than `==`
- `else` on the same line as the closing `}`
- The final statement in function `begin` does not need the test `(randN == 5 || randN == 6)` (assuming you want a new point each iteration)

### Code

The random number generated is from 0 to 6 and you ignore 0, redrawing the same point 1 in 7 times. You can reduce the random to give 3 values 0,1,2 and perform the correct calculation on that or use a counter and cycle the points.

You could also put the points `pA`, `pB`, `pC` in an array and index them directly via the random number.

Rather than use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout`. That way you don't need to clear the timer each time.

Put magic numbers in one place and name them as constants.

You reset the start point each time `delay` is called (first two lines). Better to just let it keep going. It may also pay to stop the rendering after a fixed amount of points have been rendered.

### The rewrite.

This is just an example of the various points outlined above.

Also a few modifications

- Automatically adjust number of points rendered to keep the GPU load steady.
- Stop rendering after a fixed number of points rendered.
- The starting points `pA,pB,pC` are in an array.
- Magic numbers as constants.
- Using a single render path to draw all points per render cycle.
- Using a working point `wPoint` to hold coordinates rather than create a new point for each point rendered.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


const padding = 5;
const renderDelay = 200;
const maxTime = 2;  // time in ms allowed to render points.
const maxPointsToDraw = canvas.width * canvas.height * (1 / 3); 

var pointsPerRender = 500; // points to render per render pass
var totalPoints = 0; // count of total points drawn
ctx.fillStyle = '#fc3';

const generateRand = () => Math.random() * 3 | 0;
const point = (x, y) => ({x, y});
const drawDot = p => ctx.rect(p.x, p.y, 1, 1);

const updateDot = (p, p1) => {
    p.x = p.x < p1.x ? p.x + (p1.x - p.x) / 2 : p1.x + (p.x - p1.x) / 2;
    p.y = p.y < p1.y ? p.y + (p1.y - p.y) / 2 : p1.y + (p.y - p1.y) / 2;
    return p;
}

const points = [
    point(canvas.width / 2, padding),
    point(padding, canvas.height - padding),
    point(canvas.width - padding, canvas.height - padding)
];
const wPoint = point(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 2); // working point


const renderPoints = iterations => {
    totalPoints += iterations;
    
    const now = performance.now(); 
    ctx.beginPath();
    while (iterations --) { drawDot(updateDot(wPoint, points[generateRand()])) }
    ctx.fill();
    const time = performance.now() - now;

    // use render time to tune number points to draw 
    // Calculates approx time per point and then calcs number of points
    // to render next time based on that speed.
    // Note that security issues mean time is rounded to much higher
    // value than 0.001 ms so must test for 0 incase time is zero
    pointsPerRender = maxTime / ((time ? time : 0.1)/ pointsPerRender);

    if (totalPoints < maxPointsToDraw) {
        setTimeout(renderPoints, renderDelay, pointsPerRender | 0);
    }
}
renderPoints(pointsPerRender);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```